# Как остановить уже запущенный ранее таймер?

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу разобраться как остановить уже запущенный таймер.
Смысл в том, что я хочу при повторном нажатии на кнопку сбрасывать предыдущий таймер, и запускать новый. Но у меня запускается одновременно два таймера.

Я попытался объявить переменную timer глобальной, но все равно вне объекта её тип является 'undefined'. Я только начал изучать JS, помогите, пожалуйста.

```js
var buttonOne = document.querySelector('.go');

function Timer(selector, time){
  
  var elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  window.timer = 0;
  var object = this;

  this.start = function() {
    timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  }

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  this.tick = function() {
    if (time > 0) {
      time--;
      var hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((time - (3600 * hours))/60);
      var seconds = time - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
      text = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
      document.querySelector('.time').innerHTML = text; 
    } else {
      object.stop;
    }
  }
}


buttonOne.onclick = function(){
  var userInput = document.querySelector('.seconds');
  var time = userInput.value;
  if (typeof(timer) != "undefined") {
  timer.stop();
 }
  var timer = new Timer('.time', time)
  timer.start();
}
```

```html
<input class="seconds" value="10">
<button class="go">GO!</button>
<div class="time"></div>
```

Comment: Например функцией `clearTimeout, clearInterval`

Comment: чтобы вызвать функцию нужно добавить скобки `()`

Comment: @Grundy Эмм, так у меня есть функция this.stop = function() { clearInterval(timer); }
И вызываю я ее со скобками. Вопрос в том, почему она не срабатывает.

Comment: Потому что `object.stop;` - Это не вызов функции. Вызов функции: `object.stop();`

Comment: @Grundy, object.stop; отрабатывает остановку таймера в этом блоке кода(при time < 0).
Проблема не в этом. Проблема в том, что при повторном клике я не могу остановить уже ранее запущенный таймер. То есть у меня начинают тикать два одновременно

Comment: Нет у тебя глобальной переменной.

Comment: @Qwertiy, как же нет?  `window.timer = 0;`

Comment: @RomanAndreev, можешь, просто вызови `stop` в методе `start`, перед запуском

Comment: @RomanAndreev, _object.stop; отрабатывает остановку таймера в этом блоке кода(при time < 0)_ - что не отменяет того факта, что функция `stop` Не вызывается

Comment: @Grundy Можете объяснить этот момент с вызовом функции?
Я сейчас совсем запутался. Мне нужно что бы по истечении времени Interval остановился. Он останавливается. Всё работает. Так где же ошибка и в чём принципиальная разница в object.stop и object.stop().
Кстати, я попробовал в метод start, добавить object.stop(); - вот в этом месте(при повторном клике), он почему то не срабатывает :(

Comment: @RomanAndreev, все просто: _Мне нужно что бы по истечении времени Interval остановился. Он останавливается._ - нет. Таймер не останавливается, просто он всегда попадает в ветку `else` и ты не видишь никаких изменений :) Если ты добавишь `console.log('timer stop');` в эту ветку `else` - то увидишь сколько раз она выведется.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо вам огромное. Теперь разобрался. Действительно если таким образом проверить, то консоль будет заспамлена :)
Можете объяснить, почему когда я добавляю в метод старт object.stop(), то при повторном клике таймер не останавливается? Это действительно выглядит самым логичным и красивым способом - прямо в методе старта остановить предыдущий таймер перед тем как запускать новый. Вот только реализовать не получается :(

Comment: @RomanAndreev, таймер останавливается и в самом старте ты сразу запускаешь новый. Тут у тебя решается проблема нескольких таймеров. А не старт пауза

Comment: @Grundy вот как раз таки дело в том что не решается :(
Если я повторно нажимаю кнопку старт у меня запускается два таймера и они попеременно мигают.

Comment: @RomanAndreev, тогда смотри ответы :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибок много.

1. Зачем вам глобальная переменная для интервала, если его можно отлично сохранить в классе?
2. `setInterval(this.tick, 1000);` в принципе нормально, но я бы заменил на `setInterval(object.tick, 1000);`
3. `text = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;` Переменная `text` не объявлена и попадает либо в глобальную область видимости, либо вызывает ошибку. Оно вам надо?
4. `document.querySelector('.time').innerHTML = text;` тут две ошибки

   1. Вы игнорируете переданный снаружи селектор
   2. У вас уже есть поле `elem`, соответствующее этому селектору
5. `object.stop;` это не вызов функции. Вызов функции должен быть таким `object.stop();`
6. ```
   if (typeof(timer) != "undefined")
     timer.stop();
   var timer = new Timer('.time', time);
   ```

   Проверили нет ли объекта `timer` в области видимости и создали локальный объект.

Итого:

```js
var buttonOne = document.querySelector('.go');

function Timer(selector, time){
  var elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  var timer = 0;
  var object = this;

  this.start = function() {
    timer = setInterval(object.tick, 1000);
  }

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  this.tick = function() {
    if (time > 0) {
      time--;
      var hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((time - (3600 * hours))/60);
      var seconds = time - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
      var text = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
      elem.innerHTML = text; 
    } else {
      object.stop();
    }
  }
}

var timer;

buttonOne.onclick = function(){
  var userInput = document.querySelector('.seconds');
  var time = userInput.value;
  if (typeof(timer) != "undefined") {
    timer.stop();
  }
  timer = new Timer('.time', time);
  timer.start();
}
```

```html
<input class="seconds" value="10">
<button class="go">GO!</button>
<div class="time"></div>
```

Comment: шестой пункт ошибочный. Второй - спорный

Comment: лучше, но все равно плохо

Answer (score 3):

Проблема несрабатывания условия заключается во всплытии переменных в пределах функции.

При использовании [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) возможно обращение к переменной *до* ее инициализации. При этом значением переменной будет `undefined`.

Это означает, что в следующем коде

```
if (typeof(timer) != "undefined") {
    timer.stop();
}
var timer = new Timer('.time', time)
```

В пределах функции выражение в операторе `if` всегда будет `false`, так как проверяется именно локальная переменная, которая инициализируется *после* условия, а значит в момент проверки *всегда* `undefined`.

---

Решить проблему можно простым переименованием (во всех местах использования глобальной переменной) и прямым вызовом `clearInterval`

```
if (typeof(timerId) != "undefined") {
    clearInterval(timerId)
}
```

Так как в глобальную переменную `timer` на самом деле сохраняется `id` таймера, а не создаваемый объект.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var buttonOne = document.querySelector('.go');

function Timer(selector, time){
  
  var elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  window.timer = 0;
  var object = this;

  this.start = function() {
    timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  }

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  this.tick = function() {
    if (time > 0) {
      time--;
      var hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((time - (3600 * hours))/60);
      var seconds = time - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
      text = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
      document.querySelector('.time').innerHTML = text; 
    } else {
      object.stop;
    }
  }
}


buttonOne.onclick = function(){
  var userInput = document.querySelector('.seconds');
  var time = userInput.value;
  if (typeof(timer) != "undefined") {
        timer.stop();
    }
  var timer = new Timer('.time', time)
  timer.start();
}
```

```html
<input class="seconds" value="10">
<button class="go">GO!</button>
<div class="time"></div>
```